# find() alternatives while searching in "<class 'scapy.layers.inet.IP'>"

Tags: python-2.7, http, tcp, tuples, scapy

I used TCP and HTTP to send a GET request into a site and  as an answer i got a tuple. I checked it out and apparently every type of the tuple is of the form:

```html
"<class 'scapy.layers.inet.IP'>"
```

So how can i search the html file inside this tuple?

The code i used to send the GET request:

```html
 getStr = "GET / HTTP/1.1\r\nHost: "+ URL +"\r\n\r\n"
 request = ip/ TCP(dport=80, sport=SYNACK[TCP].dport, seq=SYNACK[TCP].ack, ack=SYNACK[TCP].seq, flags ='P' and 'A') / Raw(getStr)
 send_get = sr(request, multi=1, timeout =5)
```

Comment: Can you add the python code you used to create and send the request?

Comment: The code was added :) @cnicutar